# How to retrieve Performance MAX campaigns Google Ads into Google Big Query

Tags: google-bigquery, google-ads-api, google-ads-script

I am using a third-party tool that use the Adwords Reporting https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/appendix/reports/all-reports to retrieve data.

At the moment all the "Performance Max" campaigns are lost from the Adwords Reporting and I need to retrieve them to include their costs.
With the migration from Adwords to Ads, also, I need to find a solution before April 2022.

I only need to move that data into my Google BigQuery project.

At the moment the solution using the BigQuery Data Transfer is NOT OK because use the same v201809 reporting of Adwords ( https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-transfer/docs/adwords-transfer?hl=en-GB )
.

Also the Google Ads Script don't support Google Ads but only report name of Adwords v201809 ( https://developers.google.com/google-ads/scripts/docs/solutions/bigquery-exporter )

Do you have a suggestion to help me?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Remember: Do not select an AdGroup when querying Performance Max campaigns**, as no campaigns will be returned.
https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/performance-max/reporting

Solution --> I use two different GAQL :

- one `FROM ad_group` for the details needed with the `ad_groups` resource
- another `FROM campaign` without any `ad_group` in the `SELECT`

Answer (score 0):

You have several options and the solutions depends on level in which you want to report data. On campaign level you can fetch data about impressions, clicks and cost from Google Analytics API if you have connected ads and analytics accounts.
If you want more granular information you can create report in google ads and schedule downloads of this report, for example everyday. Only problem is that performance max campaigns combine multiple types of ads, so on some dimensions you can get no data, for example campaign spend 50 eur yesterday, but in report with product id this campaign spent only 25. I combine this two sources, it isn't ideal, but better than total blindness now days.

Comment: I am using Google Ads python API but I continue to have the same problem. Data of campaign type performance max are missing in the result of my GAQL.

Comment: and at the time they will miss. Maby they will fix in in the future.